# How to check if node is being rendered inside view?

Tags: 7, views

I need to check inside node template if its contents are being rendered through view or not. What is the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unaware of a good way to do this.  However, the proper Drupal way is to not have one part of a template rely on where it is being used.  If something needs to be different, then render it out in a different manner.

For nodes in views, you can accomplish this with [custom node view modes](http://mearra.com/blogs/juha-niemi/drupal-7-custom-node-view-modes).  Essentially, you implement [`hook_entity_info_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7), and create new view modes (ones inaddition to Full and Teaser).  You can then use the **Manage Display** tab on the content type page to set up how you want the new mode to work, and then set up your view to use **Node style: Row** with your new display mode.  Also look at @Andy's answer on [How to add additional display(view mode) for node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37446/how-to-add-additional-displayview-mode-for-node) for some options that make this easier to do just from the UI.

Comment: Thanks, first link was very useful. I've implemented a new custom display type for node and crated template for it.

Answer (score 4):

You can check to see if `$view` is set and is an object in the template file; if it does, it means the node is being rendered in a View. From there you can even check that the View is the correct one if you need to.

```
if (isset($view) && is_object($view)) :
  // Do something
endif;
```