# How to add additional display (view mode) for all node types?

Tags: 7

Firstly, I've seen [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37446/how-to-add-additional-displayview-mode-for-node/37488#37488) question, have followed the steps in the answer by FranCarstens to no vail.

To clarify: I want to add custom views to all content types. (as a side question, would be nice to know how to target a specific node type, if possible).

I've created the modules, enabled it but it doesn't show as an option in any of my content types.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programm way from related quedtion should work, but it doesn't, you can try to use the following module: https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode

> The Drupal 7 successor to Build modes which will allow administrators to define custom view modes for entities.

Comment: I have added the module but cannot make it work. How do I add the extra views?

Comment: Go to the `admin/config/system/entity-view-modes/add/node` page.