# Where can I alter the path of the anchor around a views items title?

Tags: 7, views, hooks

I have a view with several items and they link to their respective nodes.
However I also have an external URL field which if populated needs to replace the path around the title of the views item.

I've been looking for a hook that builds this title path and associates it with the title but so far have not had any luck.

I thought `hook_views_pre_render()` might have it but the title is just a string.

Comment: `needs to replace the path around the title of the views item` replace the path of the nodes? So instead of going to the node, it goes to external url?

Comment: @No Sssweat interesting proposal. Yes, if an external path field is populated we link this node to that path in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @No Sssweat interesting proposal. Yes, if an external path field is
>   populated we link this node to that path in the view. – dibs

For example: I created a field called **external url**

In you view add field **path** then **external url** and then **title**

They need to be in this specific order for it to work

[image]

Then for path:

[image]

For external url:

[image]

For Title:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked a treat. Now I will have to regrow all the hair I tore out.

Comment: @dibs, you're welcome, haha.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this would be through a view mode (e.g. teaser) and a preprocess function.

Here's what you would need to do:

1. Change view display from fields to nodes.
2. Set the node view mode to be teaser. If you are already using teasers for something else, I suggest creating a new view mode for this. You can do this through your [custom module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/37488/8623), [Entity view modes](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) or [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) modules.
3. In `hook_preprocess_node()` you can make all conditions you need, and instead of showing the node URL, use the external link.

This will not only be easy to use, but very self explanatory later on.

For more information, see answers to [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/37446/8623) question.